# Issue with URI in cloneCollection command

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two separate mongoDBs on our network. I want to periodically copy collections from a production like db to our testing dbs. I think clone collection is the simplest way to do this but I can't get the URI correct.

I'm getting the error more than one ':' detected.  If this is an ipv6 address, it needs to be surrounded by '[' and ']';

Well I've tried reformatting the URI in several different ways but i haven't gotten it correct yet and continue to get errors.

This is what i think should work:

```
db.cloneCollection('mongodb://username:password@www.server.com/dbname', 'equipment', {})
```

I expect to be able to clone the collection sitting in another db to the current db.

Answer (score 0):

From [mongodb document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.cloneCollection/#authorization)

> db.cloneCollection() cannot be used if the from server has authorization enabled.